# Statistical study of the effectiveness of this site

Tags: discussion, statistics

Is there a statistical study of how many questions on this site get answered immediately or fairly quickly and correlated with the difficulty of the question or where it occurs in the academic study sequence, or answered satisfactorily with the first response, remain unanswered for long etc?

Comment: I Guess data for this exist relatively easily  obtainable, but dont know how to obtain it. Anybody know?

Comment: Use the data explorer. You will need to learn some basic database usage. But that can be picked up by reading some of the sample queries available at http://data.stackexchange.com/math/queries

Comment: Do you have a good idea as to how to measure "how difficult" a question is? I suppose looking at tags would be one thing: perhaps [tag:topology] is harder than [tag:algebra-precalculus], for instance. Do you have an idea that gives a finer sieve?

Comment: This older question is somewhat similar (at this moment, it does not have an answer): http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/8871/statistics-for-mse-visitors-before-the-fist-answer-and-answer-rate-per-tag